# Will the following F# .NET code be evaluated at runtime?

Tags: .net, f#

I have put together a basic command line application to understand the workings of the .NET runtime better. In particular, I want to know whether certain code that is declared prior to a branching statement will actually run if the subsequent branching statement renders it unnecessary for the program's output?

My F# code for a simple Console Application (with comments) below:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    // I have given the input "2" at the command line
    let (status, result) =  System.Int32.TryParse argv.[0]

    let a = 1
    let b = 2000 * 5 + 9    // Will this ever be evaluated at runtime ??

    let fa x = x + 1
    let fb x = x + 200      // In a similar vein, will this need to be declared at RUNTIME

    let answer = 
        if result > 1 then
            fa a            // the path it will take at RUNTIME
        else
            fb b            // the path it will NOT take at RUNTIME

    printfn "%d" answer

    System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

In summary: `b` and `fb` will certainly be compiled into the executable BUT will they actually be evaluated for the purposes of this running program or will the *runtime* optimize them away *at runtime*?

Comment: Why do you care about this - you can use an IL disasembler to find out anyway?

Comment: As a hint, change `let b...` to `let b = 2000 / 0` and see what happens ;)

Comment: @TimRogers thanks. I hadn't seen the connection between what I was asking and `lazy` computation till you mentioned it.

Comment: @JohnPalmer I am trying to generate/compile code via F# quotation expressions and want to understand the runtime behaviour of the resulting code given that there is potentially significant branching required (making large portions of code redundant).